# Integer cannot be resolved to a type error

Tags: java, wrapper

Got `Integer cannot be resolved to a type error` when using Integer in the code or `The import java.lang.Integer cannot be resolved` when trying to import `java.lang.Integer` explicitly, the errors do not happen with other wrappers:

MainClass.java:

```
package test;

import java.lang.Double;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Integer intWrapper = 4;
        Double doubleWrapper = 8.0d;
    }
}
```

Image:

[image: Code]

Without imports:

[image: Code 2]

Comment: That sounds like a broken JDK. The fact that it works with `Double` suggests that you have a JDK set up and only Integer is broken - does it work without the unnecessary import statements?

Comment: You normally don't need import statements for the java.lang package. What happens when you remove the import statements?

Comment: You got it _in what_ though? Because, that's an editor warning, not a java compile error, so did you try to compile your code using `javac` directly? Does that work? If so, time to update your IDE (or if it's up to date, do some searching to see if this is a known issue with it).

Comment: I agree that a broken or misconfigured JDK or IDE is the most likely explanation. But there is another possibility.  The (fully qualified) class name that you are importing there *might* contain homoglyphs.  Try retyping `java.lang.Integer`.  (Or simply removing both imports.  They are unnecessary since classes in `java.lang` are imported by default.)

Comment: Do you define right path to JRE(JDK) in your Eclipse?

Comment: did you follow the *usual* procedures: save the file, clean the project (aka rebuild: menu  `Project`-`Clean...`), close and re-open Eclipse (that looks very much like Eclipse) ?

Comment: @f1sh  Yes, I uploaded image without the import.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS It gives me error.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Integer cannot be resolved to a type

 at Project2/test.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:6)`

Comment: @WladimirDiskowski Yes.

Comment: @JamesB don't put details in comments. [put details in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

The error, "Integer cannot be resolved to a type," is due to the import statement for java.lang.Integer. Since it is already part of the Java language's core, importing it explicitly  confuses the compiler. simply remove the import statements for `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.Double` and the code will run absolutely fine

Comment: It doesn't "confuse" the compiler. It's entirely valid (though unnecessary) to import `java.lang.Integer`. After making the `main` method static, the OP's code compiles with no warnings or errors (although I'd advise them to avoid the legacy array syntax.)

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the correction.... can you please explain how it would work if we make the main method static?? i can't figure out a possible reason for it

Comment: @nischalsharma: What do you mean by "explain how it would work"? Do you mean "explain why there's an error"? No, there isn't enough information in the question to know that, basically. But it's *not* because of the imports.

Comment: @JonSkeet adding the import of some lang class should not interfere with compilation

Comment: @JamesB: That's exactly what I've been saying...